# Am I correct in my understanding of an alternative view of matrix inversion?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question, terminology, definition, inverse

We were taught in linear algebra that in order to try to find the inverse of a matrix we can create an augmented matrix $[AI]$ where $A$ is the original matrix and $I$ is the identity matrix. Then we just row reduce everything and if it all checks out, the right hand side of $[AI]$ will be $A^{{-1}}$.

However, there is a brief mention in the textbook about an alternative perspective on this without providing further explanation, proof, or examples.

**This is my best attempt at an interpretation of what it is trying to convey:**

> $A^{{-1}}$ is the matrix composed of columns $[x_1 x_2 x_n]$ where $x_1, x_2, x_n$ are solutions to the equations $Ax_1=e_1,Ax_2=e_2,Ax_n=e_n$. Where $e_n$ are the respective columns of the identity matrix

**Is my comprehension of the following correct? Please see original text below:**

---

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's helpful to remember that if $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix and $B$ is an $n\times p$ matrix, then the $i$-th column of $AB$ is $A$ times the $i$-th column of $B$. So if you're looking for a matrix $B$ such that $AB=I$, you want $A$ times the $i$-th column of $B$ to be $e_i$. In other words, you must solve $Ax=e_i$.

Comment: @symplectomorphic to be quite honest Ive never been fond with the whole subscripts thing. Like if I have a picture or diagram to show what is going on, OK. and subscripts are okay too if its just used to reference the aforementioned pictures. However if the explanation only uses subscripts, I find it suicide inducing. As you can imagine, the majority of textbooks on tensors are my nightmare fuel

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me. are you saying you don't understand my comment? (my comment hardly uses subscripts: $e_i$ just means the $i$-th standard basis vector.) or are you explaining why you were confused? (in that case I don't quite understand either, because your own paraphrase uses subscripts.)

Comment: @symplectomorphic I understood your comment. And Im glad you answered my question. I was just making an off hand remark on the sometimes confusing nature of subscripts in multidimensional settings w/o diagrams.

Comment: The reason you feel that way about subscripts is that you expect to read mathematical notation as fast as you read a novel. That is simply impossible. Long time ago people said everything in words, not even having the notations of $+,-,\times,\div$. The key is to accept that you have to read mathematical notation slower and grasp bit by bit, simply because it is **intended** to be concise yet precise.